# Run JavaScript code on window close but not on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I want to Trigger function or event when closing browser tab using Javascript
but not on page refresh.

here is fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/SQAmG/3/

**Script**

```
     var popit = true;
 window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
      if(popit == true) {
           popit = false;
           return "Are you sure you want to leave?"; 
      }
 }
```

In the fiddle its happening but in page refresh also. can any one help me out in this issue.

Comment: a refresh unloads/loads the page - not sure you can detect the difference

Comment: Are you manually or programatically refreshing the page? If programatically, you could find a workaround, otherwise not

Answer (score 0):

Here is who I solved this problem.

I needed to know when the browser was actually closed and not refreshed because out site works on "sessions."  Customers can only have so many sessions open at a time which they pay for.  Storing the computername of the computer that has the site open allows me to keep a count of separate computers using the site.

So, i have both and load and unload function set up.  When the user leaves the page, it removes the data that tells me someone has left a view, but since the very next view also use the same master layout it immediately reloads the computer name back into the data.

Not knowing what you need to do upon closing and just not refreshing a page this might be a solution for you to look at.

I have all my views run on a Master Layout.  IN the master Layout page I have the following script

```
  window.onload = function () {
        debugger;
        var url = '@Url.Action(ACStrings.OpeningBrowser, ACStrings.HomeController)';
        var link = url;
        var args = {
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: link,
            data: args,
            success: function (response) {
            }
        });
    } 


    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        debugger;
        var url = '@Url.Action(ACStrings.ClosingBrowser, ACStrings.HomeController)';
        var link = url;
        var args = {
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: link,
            data: args,
            success: function (response) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

I can do what I need to do when the Closing fires and redo anything that needs to be set while the page loads (as in the browser just changes views)

Answer (score -2):

You cannot tell the difference between a refresh and a page close event before it has happened. However, you are able to test if a page has been refreshed after the fact.

To check if a page has been refreshed, you can set a variable in sessionStorage. Data in sessionStorage is retained until the page is closed, and is kept between refreshes and reloads.

On page load you can check for this variable, if it exists, the page has been refreshed, if not, then the page has been accessed normally (a new session). After this you should set the variable so that you can detect subsequent refreshes.

Comment: how will that help detecting if a page unload is due to a refresh or not?

Comment: It won't, which I realised just before your comment. However, I think I should leave the answer here because its as close to a solution as the Asker is likely to get.